# Hiding command prompt in a cuckoo report screenshots

Tags: security, malware, malware-detection, cuckoo

I am analyzing malware using cuckoo. But in the reports generated, the content on screen is hidden due to the command prompt running on the host machine. Is there a way to hide this command prompt? I tired:

`cuckoo submit -o arguments="- windows minimized" /path/to/binary`

and

`cuckoo submit -o arguments="/min" /path/to/binary`

But still in the final screenshots of the host machine, I can see the command prompt and it is hiding stuff behind it that I need to see.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you need to keep your VM up-to-date and ready for analysis(open separately, run or cancel(depending on your approach) updates etc.) and save that state to the pristine state you will be using for analysis.

It also means that regular issues with workstations might apply:

Without knowing much details about your analysis box, you can try guides like [this](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/command-prompt-keeps-pooping-up-007.html)